# How to apply "margin: auto" while having "left: xpx" and "position: relative"?

Tags: jquery, css

How to make margin: auto to be applied on the rest of screen (place on page), after left is set?
For example:

```
.content-grid {
    left: 220px;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    position: relative;
}
```

What is easiest approach to calculate what is left once we have left: Xpx; set?
CSS or JQuery?

Comment: Can you please create example?

Comment: Hi, @ruckie.

Here is an simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/3puv5d9x/

I have collapsible menu, and somewhere in theme is added inline css I cannot find it, only workaround I could do is adding "left", while having "margin: 0 auto", and it works.
Now I would like to calculate rest of the screen based on width of navbar.

Comment: This is a WordPress theme, and it has transform inside it which makes text blurry on Chrome.
I am trying to get similar with margin auto on this div, while pushing it with left (depending on jQuery if its collapsed or not) for Xpx.
It has also hardcoded margin: 0px; on this div, so I cannot use margin options, because I would have to use !important, and !important will stop animations, and I cannot find where is margin hardcoded, probably coming from some theme js file.

Only way I found is this, it works, but I would like to calculate rest of the window after navbar is collapsed or not.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xqhz8y72/ Navbar is absolute positioned.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this by adding parent to .content-grid.

Script

```
/* Add parent to element */
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.content-grid').wrap('<div class="grid-parent"></div>');
});

/* How to add a class to another class if the collapse menu is open */
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.sidemenu-trigger').on('click', function(e) {
        if ($(".sidemenu-trigger").hasClass("active")) {
            $('.grid-parent').addClass('collapsed-menu-grid-parent')
              .css({
                  'whatever' : 'whatever',
              });
        } else {
            $('.grid-parent').removeClass('collapsed-menu-grid-parent')
              .css({
                  'whatever' : 'whatever',
              });
        }
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.grid-parent {
    display: block;
    left: 80px;
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 80px);
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 80px);
    width: calc(100% - 80px);
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.collapsed-menu-grid-parent {
    display: block;
    left: 300px;
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 300px);
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 300px);
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```